# Обновление проверки переменной в шаблоне jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

**Что есть:** 
Есть кусок кода в шаблоне, который проверяет истинность push_notification

```
{% if not push_notification %}
    <script>
        var notification = new Notification("Это я")
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

При первой загрузке страницы, переменная push_notification, имеет значение False, дальше запускается поток с функцией, которая либо меняет её на True, либо нет и значение передаётся в шаблон

```
return render_template("index.html", posts=posts, page=page, push_notification=push_notification)
```

**Что надо:**
Как осуществить периодическую проверку переменной (скажем, раз в 15 миунт) *push_notification* в шаблоне?

Либо может есть более трушный способ осуществить задуманное?

Comment: Ну, запускать render_template каждые 15 минут?

Comment: Тогда страница будет перезагружаться, что не совсем хорошо

Comment: Ну а как ещё-то? Ваш render_template работает на сервере и возвращает целиковую html-страницу. Если вы хотите без перезагрузки страницы, то это надо писать джаваскрипт в браузере и клепать ajax-запросы, чтобы запросить у сервера свежую информацию, и Jinja2 тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Значит, всё таки js

Comment: Обращаться на сервер через ajax и возвращать нужное значение. В зависимости от него через js производить какие-то действия.

Comment: если эта переменная изменяется в зависимости от возвращаемого значения vk API (питон кидает запросы), то стоит просто юзать запросы к вк через ajax?